# Different indent values in UITableViewCell for the 6+?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm putting a UITextField inside of a UITableViewCell and to match the indent of the rest of the rows, I've set x to be 15 (which I understand to be the default indent?). It looks fine and matches the rest of the cells on 5s/6, but on the 6+, I'm seeing different results. Is there a different default on the 6+? Am I missing something here?

[On the 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8FH8.jpg)

[On the 6+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZNR7.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

// yoy would be trying 

return 15

// try this... adjust some value other than 15 if doesnt work in 6+

return self.view.frame.origin.x+15;
}
```

Comment: Running into a couple of issues with this: self.view.frame.origin.x is returning 0 for me. Also, setting an indentation doesn't seem to apply to the textField (I'm setting x in initWithFrame currently) and adding indentation seems to add in addition to the default value.